# Covalent Angular move to own component

Tags: angular, angular-material2, teradata-covalent

maybe I`m trying something totally wrong but I want for example move my toolbar content to my own component.
Before:

```
 <td-layout-nav navigationRoute="/">
        <div td-toolbar-content layout="row" layout-align="start center" flex>
            <button mat-icon-button td-menu-button tdLayoutToggle>
                <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
            </button>
            <td-search-box class="pad-top-xs" backIcon="search" placeholder="Search here" [showUnderline]="false" [debounce]="500" [alwaysVisible]="false">
            </td-search-box>
            <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
            <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
                <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
                <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
            </mat-menu>
            <a mat-icon-button matTooltip="Docs" [routerLink]="" href="https://teradata.github.io/covalent/" target="_blank">
                <mat-icon>chrome_reader_mode</mat-icon>
            </a>
        </div>

and my goal is something like
        <td-layout-nav navigationRoute="/">
            <my-own-toolbar-component></my-own-toolbar-component>
```

The problem now is my layout is getting "destroyed" 
[image]

That's because the content is now surrounded by an additional div from the component selector.
But is there a possibility to overcome this? Or is my goal totally wrong?
Here is a forked Stackblitz that shows my problem.

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/covalent-perm-drawer-aix9ao)

Comment: What's 'your own component'?  What are you exactly trying to do? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I try to move the whole code for the toolbar to an own component, like putting all the html for the toolbar and put it in a "wrapper" component

Comment: So from what I understand - you have an angular component, and you have copied a code of toolbar and put it in its view?

Comment: yes thats is it

Comment: Well first - what exactly is being destroyed?
Second - if you pushed some html code to your view, you should make sure that you've also added its CSS.

Comment: Look at the screenshoot or the stackblitz example, the problem is not css its the additional div that is generated from the selector of the component

Comment: what's your component selector name? can you publish the code of your `component.ts` file?

Comment: in the stackblitz you see the topbar.component

Comment: I see you have app-topbar. To what component would you like to move it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by using the `td-toolbar-content` attribute on your component.

```
<td-layout-nav navigationRoute="/">
    <my-own-toolbar-component td-toolbar-content></my-own-toolbar-component>
    ...
</td-layout-nav>
```